# Pandas DataFrame Output Format

Tags: python, pandas

I need help reformatting my DataFrame output for stock closing prices.

Currently my output has the Stock Symbols as Headers where I would like to have them displayed in rows. df_output =  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv5Y2.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4jEk.png

I would like to have it displayed as below:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv5Y2.png)

This is my current df_output code (not sure if this is the reason):

```
prices_df = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in assets})
```

[excel_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhE90.png)

**FULL CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
from datetime import datetime
import time
start_time = time.time()

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Stock Portfolio\\My Portfolio.xlsx', sheet_name=0, skiprows=2)


list1 = list(df['Stock Code']) 

assets = list1

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(assets)

data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date=str(datetime.now().date().replace(month=1, day=1)), 
                                                  end_date=str(datetime.now().date().replace(month=12, day=31)), 
                                                  time_interval='daily')

prices_df = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in assets})
```

Comment: have you looked into `stack()` / `unstack()`? very difficult to re-produce you case without access to your excel....  include a subset of `list1`

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now but I believe a `prices_df.stack()` (as Rob said) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check pandas functions such as https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html for operations for converting between long and wide formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
prices_df.rename_axis('Date').reset_index().melt('Date', var_name='Symbol', value_name='Price')
```

Output:

```
           Date Symbol       Price
0    2020-01-02     FB  209.779999
1    2020-01-03     FB  208.669998
2    2020-01-06     FB  212.600006
3    2020-01-07     FB  213.059998
4    2020-01-08     FB  215.220001
..          ...    ...         ...
973  2020-08-18   CDNS  109.150002
974  2020-08-19   CDNS  108.529999
975  2020-08-20   CDNS  111.260002
976  2020-08-21   CDNS  110.570000
977  2020-08-24   CDNS  111.260002

[978 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Where do I input this line?
Still receiving an error

Comment: At the very end of your code.  You'll need to reassign this to a new variable.   What error are you receiving?